# SSH to a login to Ubuntu 16 Core on Raspberry Pi3 requires password

Tags: ssh, login, raspberrypi

Just installed the core on my raspberry pi 3 but asks for password. access denied . The fingerprint is exactly the same as shown on the pi screen/console. Keys must be OK. How to go forward??

```
16:41:23.281 Current date: 2017-08-20
16:41:23.281 Bitvise SSH Client 7.34, a fully featured SSH client for Windows.
Copyright (C) 2000-2017 by Bitvise Limited.
16:41:23.281 Visit www.bitvise.com for latest information about our SSH software.
16:41:23.281 Run 'BvSsh -help' to learn about supported command-line parameters.
16:41:23.281 Cryptographic provider: Windows CNG (x86) with additions
16:41:23.500 Loading default profile.
16:41:30.286 Started a new SSH2 session.
16:41:30.286 Connecting to SSH2 server 192.168.178.19:22.
16:41:30.286 Connection established.
16:41:30.380 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
16:41:30.380 First key exchange started. Cryptographic provider: Windows CNG (x86) with additions
16:41:30.505 Received host key from the server. Algorithm: RSA, size: 2048 bits, MD5 fingerprint: fd:22:6d:5d:69:63:b6:57:e8:58:f9:92:57:b0:26:57, Bubble-Babble: xurif-giril-habas-syvyt-nifem-pybot-larik-kosop-nudad-ropym-fixux, SHA-256 fingerprint: PR6Z4cXKD/WmzwI7YRraqT6WRW713+5O4a4mCuguddk.
16:41:32.911 Host key has been saved to the global database.
16:41:32.943 First key exchange completed using diffie-hellman-group14-sha1. Session encryption and integrity: aes256-gcm, compression: none.
16:41:32.958 Attempting none authentication.
16:41:32.958 Remaining authentication methods: 'publickey,password'.
16:41:58.991 Attempting password authentication.
16:41:59.007 Authentication failed. Remaining authentication methods: 'publickey,password'.
16:42:02.394 Authentication aborted on user's request.
16:42:02.394 The SSH2 session has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is written in the first section of [all the guides](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md):

> User management in Raspbian is done on the command line. **The default user is pi, and the password is raspberry.** You can add users and change each user's password.

Comment: I know, but the question is about Ubuntu 16 core

Comment: oh ... so then you will probably have to say how did you install it and how the fingerprint is related to the process of authentication.

Comment: Try to login with different user than *root* ! maybe variable `AllowRootLogin` is set to `no`  in core *sshd* , So you won't be able to login as root . @Jandevos

Comment: I did login with a user different from root but get access denied.